# Display checkbox in multilpe columns using checkBoxList

Tags: yii, checkboxlist

I need to display checkbox in the format as shown below
[image]
And the code used to do this is as shown

```
<style>
   ul,li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
   }
   .orange{
   color: #FF6C00;
   }
   .payment_mode{
   float: left;
   width: 700px;
   margin: 0 0 8px 0;
   padding: 0 0 8px 0;
   }
   .payment_mode ul li{
   float: left;
   width: 220px;
   padding: 3px 0;
   }
   .checkboxgroup{
   overflow:auto;
   }
   .checkboxgroup div{
   width:200px;
   float:left;
   }
</style>

<div class="payment_mode">
   <p>
      <b>Payment Modes Accepted By You</b>
   </p>
   <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="select_all('cb_modes[]')"
         value="All" id="sel_all_modes" name="sel_all_modes" class="cmn"> <span
         class="orange">Select All</span>
      </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="Cash" id="cb_modes[]"
         name="cb_modes[]" class="cmn"> <span>Cash</span>
      </li>
      -----
      -----
   </ul>
</div>
```

I need to achieve the same thing using checkBoxList i tried using checkBoxList i get it as shown 
[image]

And the code to do that is as shown

```
<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('checkBoxList','',
    CHtml::listData(paymentmode::model()->findAll(), 'paymentmodeid', 'paymentmode'),array('id'=>'checklist','name'=>'checklist',
           )
);?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `template` option of the [`checkBoxList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBoxList-detail):

```
<ul>
<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('checkBoxList','',$data, array(
    'id'=>'checklist',
    'name'=>'checklist',
    'template'=>'<li>{input} {label}</li>',
));?>
</ul>
```